# Xamarin access property of a custom renderer from xaml

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, custom-renderer

I have an ios custom render for the xamarin editor and im trying to set the `Control.ScrollEnabled` property to be true on some page and false on other pages.

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ExtendedEditor), typeof(ExtendedEditorRenderer))]
namespace My.iOS.Renderers
{
    public class ExtendedEditorRenderer : EditorRenderer
    {
        public ExtendedEditor ExtendedEditorElement => Element as ExtendedEditor;

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Editor> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                Control.ScrollEnabled = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Above is my code the customer renderer. As you can see the `ScrollEnabled` property is always set to false.
Is there a way that i can get access to these properties, such as, scrollenable, bordercolor, backgroundcolor, etc.. and change them from XAML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create those `Properties/BindableProperties` on your **ExtendedEditor** control and then access those in your renderer using the `ExtendedEditorElement` property you created.

When you have the properties declared in your **ExtendedEditor** class, you can access those like below:

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Editor> e)
{
    base.OnElementChanged(e);

    if (e.NewElement != null)
    {
        Control.ScrollEnabled = ExtendedEditorElement.ScrollEnabled;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you! this was the code that i had to put in my ExtendedEditor class.

`public static readonly BindableProperty IsScrollEnabledProperty =
   BindableProperty.Create("IsScrollEnabled", typeof(bool), typeof(ExtendedEditor), false);
  public bool IsScrollEnabled
  {
   get { return (bool)GetValue(IsScrollEnabledProperty); }
   set { SetValue(IsScrollEnabledProperty, value); }
  }
`